# What happen with the syntax of this 2 python code?

Tags: python, syntax

What happens in these 2 blocks of Python code?

First

```
a=0,b=1,c=1,r=(a,b)[c]
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can´t assign to literal
```

Second

```
 r=(1,0)[1],a=1
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Python's not like C, You need to use `;` to separate multiple assignment statements. Or better assign `a,b,c = 0,1,1` Or even better go with separate lines.

Comment: I call `(a,b)[c]` in this way because I don´t know how call it in another way   :(
Thanks Bhargav Rao and cricket_007

Comment: @cricket_007 How did this get closed for being unclear? It's one of the most concise and clear questions I've ever seen here.

Comment: @StefanPochmann - Look at the edit history. I cleared it up

Comment: @cricket_007 I had already checked that. The edits didn't really make a difference, and the first version was clear already.

Comment: I just say thanks for the help and the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `;` to separate assignment statements, like this:

`a=0;b=1;c=1;r=(a,b)[c]`

and

`r=(1,0)[1];a=1`

Comment: This is the answer winner xD, Thanks man

Comment: No problem, if this answer solved your question, please consider marking it as so! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll explain **what happens** with an example that **does** work:

```
>>> a=b, c=[5,6]
```

After that, you have:

```
>>> a
[5, 6]
>>> b
5
>>> c
6
```

As you can see, it doesn't assign `b` to `a` and assign `[5,6]` to `c`. What it does is assign `[5,6]` to `a`, and then also to `b` and `c` (each getting one element). A clearer way to write it is this:

```
a = (b, c) = [5,6]
```

So when you try your

```
a=0,b=...
```

then you're actually trying to assign something to the literal `0`, which isn't allowed, which is what the error message is telling you.

Similarly, in your second example `r=(1,0)[1],a=1`, you're trying to assign `1` to `r` (which works, `r` actually is `1` afterwards) and then also assign it to the pair `(1,0)[1],a`, which doesn't work because you can't assign a single number to a pair. It's like `(a, b) = 1`.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm like water jajaja